# Add Remix OS to GRUB on MBR/BIOS

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, multi-boot, grub2

My computer has got three OSes:

1. Windows 10, the first OS I installed.
2. Ubuntu 16.04, the second I installed, replacing WBM with grub2
3. Remix OS 3 for PC (which I just installed).

Windows and Ubuntu work just fine, but Remix OS does not show up on my Grub Menu.

Here's what I did to install Remix OS:

1. Launched Windows, installed uTorrent, downloaded the 64bit legacy BIOS installation ISO.
2. Used the partition manager to delete the Linux Swap partition, shrank the Windows partition by 10GB, created a new partition with NTFS filesystem and named it REMIX, with drive letter R.
3. Started the installation procedure (with the official Remix OS installer, selected drive R:.
4. Initialized installation. Waited a few minutes.
5. Restarted PC as requested by installer.
6. My GRUB screen showed up, listing Ubuntu, advanced options for Ubuntu, Memtest86+ and Windows, but no Remix OS.

What have I done wrong? Why doesn't my GRUB bootloader detect the newly installed operating system?

P.S. All OSes still work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

as you, I have Windows (10),Ubuntu and RemixOs installed, I tried everything to boot RemixOs with GRUB2, but nothing worked, however I got to boot RemixOs


In my case, I first had only Windows 10 and Remix Os, so I installed it with the installation program that comes with remixos, so it just boot normally(boots from Windows Bootloader). Then I installed Ubuntu, after installing and rebooting,GRUB2 just showed Ubuntu (and the other options that normally shows like advances settings, memtest, etc) and Windows 10 Loader, BUT, when booting Windows 10 Loader, it shows the Windows 10 Bootloader just like before I installed Ubuntu, and therefore, I had the option to boot Windows 10, and RemixOs


I really hope you have understood this, I mostly speak spanish so I can't write in perfect english

Comment: Welcome to Super User! On this Q&A site we try to provide [good answers](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer) to questions people post. Part of providing a good answer is actually answering the posted question. In this case, OP wants to add Remix OS to GRUB, instead of having to go through GRUB and the Windows boot loader.